# unwrap element does not copy dimensions to parent element

Tags: jquery, css, layout

I'm unwrapping an href around an image. The image has certain dimensions, the href has the dimensions taken from the image including the padding. When I perform the unwrap, the parent div doesn't get the dimensions from the new direct child (img) and the layout is screwed.
What can I do?

regards,
Jeroen

Comment: Do you have a code example including the HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parent a `<span>` and give it a `display: block;` property. This should adjust to the dimensions to what's inside it.